# Unity DropDown получение текста

Tags: unity3d

В скрипте у меня есть изменяемый Dropdown, где я должен знать какой элемент выбрал пользователь, но если я делаю это, используя Dropdown.value, то при изменении Dropdown, а получаю лишь только номер выбранного пункта. И вот тут нужно получить текст элемента. Можно ли как-то это сделать?

код особо не требуется, но вот, если нужно

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class dropdown : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public Dropdown dd1;
    public Dropdown dd2;
    public GUIStyle mystyle;
    int scrap_count;
    private void Start()
    {
        scrap_count = WeaponKnowFuckingId.scrap_count;

    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        WeaponKnowFuckingId.Idfor1weapon = dd1.value;
        WeaponKnowFuckingId.Idfor2weapon = dd2.value;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(20, 0, 1000, 1000), "Scrap:" + scrap_count, mystyle);
    }
}
```

скрип WeaponKnowFuckingId просто содержит переменные с кол-во очков и выбранными пушками

Comment: Покажите код, где Вы всё это делаете.

Answer (score 1):

У экземпляра класса Dropdown есть поле [.options](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-options.html) оно даёт доступ ко всем вариантам. По вашему индексу собственно можно получить нужный элемент и вытащить из него текст.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = GetComponent<Dropdown>().options[GetComponent<Dropdown>().value].text;
   Debug.Log(s);
```

Дополняю [@M.Green](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991338/217579).